# Запрос на MySQL: подписка на комментарии

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Нужно реализовать правильный MySQL запрос. В общем, мне стало интересно, как реализовать функцию подписки на последнии комментарии.

Имеется две таблицы read: кто на кого подписан. comments - комментарии.
Таблица read имеет 2 столбца, в которой (`kto`, `kogo`) (Кто подписался (ID профиля), На кого подписался (ID профиля)).

Таблица с комментариями Comments имеет столбцы (`id`, `id_send_user`, `id_post`, `msg`, `time`) (Идентификатор записи, ID профиля отправителя, ID поста(записи), Сам комментарий, время (php - "time();")).

В MySQL я только умею основные действия выполнять, так что не знаю, как реализовать.
Готов выслушать любые предложения. Заранее спасибо.

Пробовал так:

```
SELECT * FROM comments JOIN read ON read.kogo = comments.id_send_user ORDER by time desc LIMIT 15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
User {
  id: int,
  name: name
}

Post {
  id: int,
  user: int ForeignKey_User_id,
  date: timestamp,
  text: text
}

Comment {
  id: int,
  post: int ForeignKey_Post_id,
  user: int ForeignKey_User_id,
  date: timestamp,
  text: text
}

Subscription {
  user_src: int ForeignKey_User_id,
  user_dst: int ForeignKey_User_id
}

//15 последних комментариев людей на которых я подписался
$query = mysql_query(
  'SELECT c.* FROM Comment c, Subscription s '.
  'WHERE c.user = s.user_src AND s.user_dst = '.$MyID.' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 15'
);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Разобрался! Мне достаточно было лишь сделать правильный запрос, но Вы что-то и поверх этого написали.

Comment: Дополнительно - структура таблиц на псевдо-коде... Как минимум - присмотритесь к названиям полей)